# Add/Remove Listener Globally to all the activity

Tags: java, android, listener

My Application have around 50 activities to which I want to register/De-register my listener. Traditional way could be to register it by writing it in every activity. Is there any way to define my listener globally.

Comment: Traditionally it is done by using inheritance. One base class with your listener and all other activities inherit from.it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think 50 activities are too much and I think you are doing something wrong.

Secondly, for your situation, you could make `BaseActivity` and register and unregister your listener in the appropriate lifecycle event.

```
class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        //register your listener here
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        //unregister your listener here 
    }
}
```

and then rather than extending Activity, you will extend the `BaseActivity`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you registering your activities at a central registrar, maybe a synchronized Set or List (I guess you need to implement a common interface for all your activities to be able to do so). Then your listener would be able to process this list and register at each and every activity.
Or the listener would just register at this central registrar. Thus, the registrar would be acting as a publisher as well, and passing subscriptions down to all registered activities.